# Fusionar 3 tablas de Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, wordpress

Buenas noches a todos.

Llevo ya más de un mes intentando dar con la clave, pero no hay manera.

Estoy ayudando a un amigo a crear una página web, la cual tiene 2 instalaciones de Wordpress, una la usa como tienda y la otra más tipo web de información y blog, ya que ambas usan themes distintos. Con tutoriales de internet conseguimos fusionar las dos tablas en una sola, asi como que el usuario que se logea, pueda pasar de una web a otra sin perder el login.

En la web hay 3 formas de que un usuario cree una cuenta (introduciendo los datos de nombre, mail, contraseña y teléfono):

1. Con una pagina de login/registro a través de s2member.
2. A través de un plugin tipo booking cuando contrata una reserva.
3. Cuando realiza una compra por tienda de Woocomerce.

Los datos tales como nombre, mail y contraseña se comunican entre los 3 sistemas, por lo que si el usuario ha creado una cuenta con cualquiera de las 3 maneras, se sincronizan dichos datos, menos el teléfono, ya que no está dentro de Wp_users, sino de wp_usermeta como wp_s2member_custom_fields en caso de s2member o billing_phone para woocomerce.

He conseguido que, por ejemplo, al autorellenar un formulario con los datos, pueda llamar por separado a cada valor poniendo esto en functions.php:

```
wpcf7_add_shortcode( 'cf7_extra_fields', 'cf7_extra_fields_func', true );
function cf7_extra_fields_func( $atts ) {
   $customer = OsAuthHelper::get_logged_in_customer();
   $html = '';
   $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="page-title" value="'.get_the_title().'" />';
   $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="page-url" value="'.get_the_permalink().'" />';
   $html .= '<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="user-phone" value="'.get_user_field("phone").'" /></span>';
   $html .= '<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="user-phone" value="'. $customer->phone .'" /></span>';
   $html .= '<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="user-phone" value="'.get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'billing_phone', true).'" /></span>';
   return $html;

}
```

El problema con esto es que, cada resultado refleja el teléfono según el método de registro y los otros dos estarán vacíos, a diferencia de con nombre, apellidos y correo, ya que esa información, se registre por donde se registre, va a la misma tabla. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer lo mismo con el teléfono y así tener una sola llamada a ese teléfono en dicho código?

Me pasa lo mismo con las dos instalaciones, tengo instalado en ambos s2member y me sincroniza entre ambos los roles, nombre, apellidos, correo, etc. Pero no el custom field ni por ejemplo las administrative notes o el EOT. Para ello, me gustaría saber como llamar por ejemplo, si se ha registrado en la instalación 2 de wordpress y allí le aparecen esos datos "extras", cuando esté en la 1 y vaya a usuarios, ver esos datos también rellenados.